# Objects array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm studying Javascript and I have this sample program that shows how to use a module.

There is a "products" array and I couldn't find out what "products[productName]" is meant to do in this program. If I understand correctly, in Javascript, an array always uses numbered indexes and doesn't work if you use named indexes.

As much as I expect, like this objects array is made in this program.

```
products = [ {productName: 0,} ]
```

I'm looking forward to helping me. Thank you in advance.

```js
var store = {};

shop.cart = (function() {
  var products = [];
  function addProduct(productName) {
    if(!products[productName]) {
      // If the product is not added into the shopping cart, add it there.
         products[Productname] = 0;
    }
    // Raise the number of products by one
    products[productName]++;
  }

  function totalProducts() {
    var amount = 0;
    for(var productName in products) {
      amount += products[Productname];
    }
    return amount;
  }

  // interface
  return {
    add: addProduct,
    productAmount: productTotal
  };
})();

store.cart.add("keksi");
store.cart.add("keksi");
store.cart.add("apple");
console.log(store.cart.productAmount()); // 3
```

Comment: For starters, it seems you've consfused `store` and `shop`.
I suggest you fix this mixup and then see if you can understand the program.

Comment: You have not shown where your `productTotal` is and you're confusing `store` and `shop`.

Comment: I think you should not store it inside the array `products = [ {productName: 0,} ]` it is sufficient `products = {productName: 0,}`` and then you can access products[productName]

Comment: Does this code run without errors?  I'm looking at `for(var productName in products) {
      amount += products[Productname];
    }` and noticing that `Productname` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. Javascript is case-sensitive. `Products[productName]` returns the element in the `Products` object with the name stored in the variable `productName`.